# Android Studio Gradle stuck

Tags: android, gradle, installation, debian, android-gradle-plugin

I'm a newby in Android Studio but I finally managed to install it under Debian 8.1 following this tutorial: http://www.17od.com/2014/11/12/installing-android-studio-on-debian-wheezy/.

I immediately created a project and built it, but gradle is stuck (up to now it's 20 minutes) creating debug sources.

May I ask some help to get it work properly? Thanks![image]

Comment: Do you happen to be running behind a proxy or other connection blockers?

Comment: .. nope! home wifi only, with no proxy added!

Comment: I think the first time it runs it downloads required sdk and building tool components, that may be the reason, but it should be a one time thing only

Comment: Nope! I've just downloaded all SDK tools and already run the emulator, but there is now way that Gradle window disappears..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure 'Auto-detect Proxy settings' is checked under Preferences -> Appearance and Behaivour -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy